# How to read or save a file from MultiValueDict in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, multi-value-dictionary

I'm sending a excel file from Angular to Django. I want to read the file using Pandas and perform some operations in the file, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
class fileupload(APIView) :
    def post(self, request): 
        f = request.FILES
        print(f)
```

When I print, it shows below,

```
<MultiValueDict: {'excelfile': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: New_Excel.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]}>
```

Here, I want to save this file to some location and use pandas to perform operations or if possible, directly would need to read the file using pandas. I'm new to Django and Pandas so if anything is wrong, please help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage    
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
file_objs = request.data.getlist('files')
for file_obj in file_objs:
    path = default_storage.save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ContentFile(file_obj.read()))
    print("images path are",path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class fileupload(APIView) :
def post(self, request): 
    f = request.data.getlist("excelfile")
    print(f) # list of elements
```

Now loop the f then store one by one

Comment: Hi, I see this. `[<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]` . How to save the file after this.. Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: Once you got List of memory objects then loop it, 
for index,value in enumerate(f):
     Tablename.object.cretae(attribute_name=value)